# How do you refresh ckeditor?

Tags: ckeditor, refresh

By clicking a button I insert some HTML tags to the ckeditor textarea

```
$("#btn_copy_url").on('click', function() {     
    insertAtCaret('editor','<p><img alt="" src="images/test.jpg" /></p>');
});
```

insertAtCaret() is a function that insert the code at cursor position.

It didn't work at first, but then I noticed the added element appears if I refresh the page, I guess what I'm missing is to refresh the editor instance.
I just don't know how.

Comment: Tried with updateElement() but didn't work

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to fix this issue but found the way to do the same using the ckeditor API: insertHtml()